# How can I add a conditional environment statement in my ember-cli index.html file?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to only include my google analytics snippit only for my production environment.

It would be great to be able to keep the snippit in the head of my ember-cli index.html file template in production and not for my development build.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the ember-cli-google-analytics addon?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-google-analytics

Check the link and look under Configuration - if you only configure a `webPropertyId` under production, then the snippet will only be injected into your index file when in production.

The addon was rated a 7/10 and was updated a month ago (I am not the author and have no affiliation, btw).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to roll your own, you can add a `content-for` tag to your `index.html`:

```
{{content-for 'ga'}}
```

then provide the content in your `Brocfile.js`:

```
var app = new EmberApp({});
if (EmberApp.env() === 'production') {
    app.options.inlineContent = {
        ga: "<script>/* google analytics script here */</script>"
    };
}
```

(Caveat: For some reason the `inlineContent` part is missing from the Ember-CLI docs - it only mentions the use of [`content-for` for addons](http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#content), so I don't know if the API is changing).

Comment: [ember-cli-inline-content](https://github.com/gdub22/ember-cli-inline-content) 

@Truffula I needed to reference  app.env === 'production' and I needed to set the content attribute of the ga key.